# how to create a page only can be visited by admin using django

Tags: django, pinax

how to do this

and

has pinax any app do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django provides a decorator for testing a user at the view-level.  You can use this to enforce an "admin-only" for a given view.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff)
def my_admin_only_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...

# could also test for superuser only, or whatever else you like
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
```